# Не выводит имя двоечника

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры, циклы

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
#define N 4
struct mystruct {
    int pp_num;
    char *fio;
    char *mark;
    int groupe_num;

};

int main() {
    mystruct a[N];
    a[0].pp_num = 1;
    a[0].fio = "Yarmolenko A.A";
    a[0].mark = "4,5,5,3,4";
    a[0].groupe_num = 12;

    a[1].pp_num = 2;
    a[1].fio = "Pyatov A.V";
    a[1].mark = "3,4,5,4,3";
    a[1].groupe_num = 23;

    a[2].pp_num = 3;
    a[2].fio = "Shevchenko A.M";
    a[2].mark = "4,3,4,2,4";
    a[2].groupe_num = 34;

    a[3].pp_num = 4;
    a[3].fio = "Garmash D.H";
    a[3].mark = "3,5,3,4,4";
    a[3].groupe_num = 43;


    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        char c[2] = "2";
        char *b;
        b = strpbrk(a[3].mark,c);
        if (b!=NULL)
        {

            cout << a[i].fio << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

должно вывести фамилию Shevcenko но не работает не могу разобраться

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

1) Вы перебираете в цикле все элементы массива, но ищете `"2"` только в четвёртом элементе: *strpbrk(a[**3**].mark,c)* :-)

2) Почему `strpbrk()`?

3) Зачем `c[]` создаётся и инициализируется на каждой итерации, и вообще - не константа?

```
const char c[] = "2";
/* ... */
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
{
    /* 
      а если ищем только "2", то можно ещё проще:
         const char c = '2';
          ...   
         !strchr(a[i].mark, c)
    */
    if ( !strstr(a[i].mark, c) )
    {
        cout << a[i].fio << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вам следует включить заголовок `<cstring>`, так как вы используете функции, объявленные в этом заголовке.

```
#include <cstring>
```

Строковые литералы в C++ имеют тип константных символьных массивов, то есть `const char[N]`, где `N` - это количество символов, включая завершающий ноль, в строковом литерале. А потому указатели на строковые литералы также должны иметь квалификатор `const`, то есть правильно было бы определить вашу структуру как

```
struct mystruct {
    int pp_num;
    const char *fio;
    const char *mark;
    int groupe_num;
};
```

В цикле у вас проверяется всегда один и тот же элемент массива с индексом 3

```
b = strpbrk(a[3].mark,c);
```

Поэтому в этом случае нет большого смысла использовать цикл. Более того этот элемент не имеет `'2'` в поле `mark`

```
a[3].pp_num = 4;
a[3].fio = "Garmash D.H";
a[3].mark = "3,5,3,4,4";
a[3].groupe_num = 43;
```

Поэтому правильно было бы записать

```
char c[] = "2";

for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    if ( strpbrk( a[i].mark, c ) != nullptr )
    {
        cout << a[i].fio << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Если ищется только одна оценка в поле `mark`, то альтернативой для функции `strpbrk` может быть также функция `strstr` или `strchr` (так как оценка может быть представлена одним символом).
Преимущество функции `strpbrk` состоит в том, что вы можете искать любую из заданных оценок. Например

```
char c[] = "23";
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    if ( strpbrk( a[i].mark, c ) != nullptr )
    {
        cout << a[i].fio << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к остальным мои 5 копеек :)

Раз уж у вас C++, не надо использовать

```
#define N 4
```

Пишите вместо этого куда более безопасное со всех точек зрения

```
constexpr int N = 4;
```

или, если компилятор старый и не понимает `constexpr`,

```
const int N = 4;
```

Еще - да, в вашем конкретном случае такой фокус

```
a[0].fio = "Yarmolenko A.A";
```

работает, но концептуально так поступать не стоит. Потому что при переделке программы у вас может присваиваться строка, например, вводимая с клавиатуры в какой-то буфер. При таком присвоении вы сохраните только указатель на буфер, в котором после очередного ввода будет уже совсем другая строка. Строку лучше копировать в свой внутренний буфер.